# PostgreSQL using substring

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a query where it extracts the country only from a column. The column looks as follow.

```
Label:
456.United_States.NYC
4589.United_States
789.United_States.NYC.Manhattan_Level
506.India.Bangladesh_3
```

Comment: What did you try? What is the expected results exactly (in regards to the 4th line)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5870f1b8f233015bbb7b826f88e63e4b)

You can use `split_part()`

```
SELECT
    split_part(my_column, '.', 2) as country
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Thank you I tried that and I got an error message, saying that the "function plit_part(ltree,unknown,integer) does not exist: Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types, you might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Well... two points: Read what the message says: 'plit_part' does not exist. That's true, because, it's called 'split_part'. Second: You didn't say, that your column is of type `ltree`. As you wrote above, one think, that is a simple string. For ltree you can read the manual here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html. You have two options: First, you can cast your column to text: `my_column::text` or use the ltree function: `subltree(my_column, 1, 2)` which returns a ltree as well. If the output type should be of type text, you can cast it afterwards as well...

Comment: I've noticed that like if the country still has the underscore; example United_states, how do I remove the underscore so that it is only United States?

Comment: For example `replace` function: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=fe2ce06c855358f43c53b13ea553404e I suggest to read the postgres string manual. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html